# Text classification using embedding for two columns of dataset

Tags: layer, text-classification, embedding, word-embedding

I am working on a project where i am using mental health related subreddit posts containing two feature columns (text, title) and a label column (Subreddit).
I want to use LSTM for classification where i need to create embedding matrix for both the columns in short need both columns for text classification but i cannot find the way to embed both columns.
Code i am using for text sequences is

```
text_sequences_train = token.texts_to_sequences(preprocessed_text_train)
title_sequences_train = token.texts_to_sequences(preprocessed_title_train)
#print(sequences_train)
train=np.hstack(text_sequences_train+title_sequences_train)
train.reshape(1,train.shape[0])
train_seq_x=pad_sequences(train, maxlen=300)

text_sequences_test = token.texts_to_sequences(preprocessed_text_test)
title_sequences_test = token.texts_to_sequences(preprocessed_title_test)
#print(sequences_train)
test=np.hstack(text_sequences_test+title_sequences_test)
test.reshape(1,test.shape[0])
test_seq_x=pad_sequences(test, maxlen=300)

text_sequences_val = token.texts_to_sequences(preprocessed_text_val)
title_sequences_val = token.texts_to_sequences(preprocessed_title_val)
#print(sequences_train)
val=np.hstack(text_sequences_val+title_sequences_val)
val.reshape(1,val.shape[0])
val_seq_x=pad_sequences(val, maxlen=300)
```

the above code gives me an error

```
ValueError: `sequences` must be a list of iterables. Found non-iterable: 428.0
```

code i am using for embedding matrix is

```
glove_file = "glove.42B.300d.txt"
import tqdm

EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH = 300 # <=200
def construct_embedding_matrix(glove_file, word_index):
  embedding_dict = {}
  with open(glove_file,'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        values=line.split()
        # get the word
        word=values[0]
        if word in word_index.keys():
            # get the vector
            vector = np.asarray(values[1:], 'float32')
            embedding_dict[word] = vector
            #print(embedding_dict[word].shape)
###  oov words (out of vacabulary words) will be mapped to 0 vectors

num_words=len(word_index)+1
#initialize it to 0
embedding_matrix=np.zeros((num_words, EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH))
for word,i in tqdm.tqdm(word_index.items()):
    if i < num_words:
        vect=embedding_dict.get(word, [])
        if len(vect)>0:
            embedding_matrix[i] = vect[:EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH]
            #print(embedding_matrix[i].shape)
print(embedding_matrix)
return embedding_matrix
```

embedding_matrix=construct_embedding_matrix(glove_file, word_index)

If I convert text sequences and then train test split it gives an error where X and Y no of samples do not match